# Securing REST using JAVA and an iPhone App using Appcelerator

Tags: java, javascript, restful-authentication, appcelerator

i have developed a test RESTFUL webservice using spring that returns test json data., and an iPhone App using Titanium Appcelerator.,

i was able to communicate with the Service effectively using POST requests from iPhone.,,

the problem is that how do i authenticate the user every time they call some API from iPhone.,

should i send Username and Password for every API call , if so how do i send it securely, currently using POST , is POST secure enough.

or do i have to encrypt the username and password and send it on POST if so what are the top secure algorithms that can be considered...

any other methods will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is secure REST calls by HTTP basic and SSL. In Java (as you're using Spring) you can simply use Spring Security.